# Ant Design: How to prevent expansion when clicked on the Collapse header, but allow on a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Ant's Collapse component, which has a `header` with some text on `Collapse.Panel`. Also there's a `Button` component next to the header text. I need to allow Collapse's expansion only on button click, and not on the overall panel. I have tried to depict the UI here, as I can't post the screenshots.

```
 ____________________________________________________________
|                                                            |
|Panel Header Text <-- prevent                               |
|[Button]     <-- allow                                      |
|____________________________________________________________|
```

[Ant's document](https://3x.ant.design/components/collapse/) have `onChange` method but it doesn't cater to an click event (which I could prevent to not make Collapse exapnd). How to restrict and allow some elements on that header to allow/prevent this collapsible behaviour?

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-payne-ezpdn

Comment: Can you add codesandbox of what you trying to achieve?

Comment: The document demo would be good enough to let others have a try

Comment: I have added the link. You can see panel exapnds/collapses on clicking anywhere on the header, which I want to restrict to the Button only.

Comment: You can't, its not supported tey

Comment: Of course. I am wondering what could be the possible workarounds, until Ant officially comes up with something that caters this requirement.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar situation with radio buttons on the panel header. selecting a radio button causes the collapse to expand.

Comment: No mate @cbutler. Thankfully my requirement was not hard pressing, so I carried on with the way it is. But you can try something this: look at the `disabled` prop on Collapse.Panel. Set it to true initially. Then on click of radio button, change it to false. And then `forceRender` the panel. I haven't tried this, but if you succeed, post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your header node to this:

```
const panelHeader = (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Row onClick={event => event.stopPropagation()}><Col><Typography.Text>Header</Typography.Text></Col></Row>
    <Button>Expand</Button>
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Your panel node should be:

```
<Panel showArrow={false} header={panelHeader} key="1">
      <p>{text}</p>
</Panel>
```

and add this Css to your styles:

```
.ant-collapse > .ant-collapse-item > .ant-collapse-header {
   padding: 0 !important;
}

.ant-btn {
   position: absolute;
   left: 15px;
   bottom: 15px;
}

.ant-typography {
   display: block;
   height: 80px;
   margin-left: 15px;
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```

You should add your arrow icon node in Row that has stopPropagation method.